# Where is weather indicator on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

I've installed a weather indicator (name of the indicator is My-Weather indicator) on my Linux Mint 14 successfully. I've installed it by using terminal with the following commands

```
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

It works great, but when I change the weather updates source to Yahoo, then suddenly it's gone. I've restarted my PC many times, but no luck. Every time when I click on the icon to open it, the mouse pointer shows busy for few seconds, seems it's gonna start, but nothing happens. After that I opened system monitor to see the running processes, weather indicator isn't even on the list.

I really love that indicator, how can I get back that?

Comment: Looks like you have set the weather sources badly. Does it work OK if you set the back to whatever they were?

Comment: @terdon, Yes, it's OK to set back my previous source. But I can't get the window to set back the source, that's the problem.

Comment: Please update your question with an explanation of what "My Weather" is and how you installed it. The settings will be somewhere in your $HOME, probably in $HOME/.config. You should be able to edit the appropriate text file.

Comment: @terdon details added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator/+bug/1163457) and My-Weather indicator cannot work with yahoo. The easiest way to fix this seems to be deleting/renaming My-Weather Indicator's configuration file:

```
mv ~/.config/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.conf weather.conf.bak
```

Now, relaunch the applet and it should work again.

Comment: WOW!! This works just like a magic. Thank you very much.